# GCC and Clang can't compile C++ code

Tags: c++, cpp

Trying to run command `gcc code.cpp -o runthis`

However it gives me errors in this format:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cco6J3Vh.o: warning: relocation against `_ZSt4cout' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cco6J3Vh.o: in function `main':
code.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `std::cout'
/usr/bin/ld: code.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: code.cpp:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `std::cin'
/usr/bin/ld: code.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `std::istream::operator>>(int&)'
/usr/bin/ld: code.cpp:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `std::cout'
/usr/bin/ld: code.cpp:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: code.cpp:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: code.cpp:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `std::cout'
/usr/bin/ld: code.cpp:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: code.cpp:(.text+0xe6): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cco6J3Vh.o: in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
code.cpp:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/usr/bin/ld: code.cpp:(.text+0x148): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

From checking it out online, it seems to be a linker issue. I'm on Arch Linux. Clang gives me the same error as gcc however I can compile using c++. Any help is appreciated

Comment: @StephenKitt yes it seems to compile through that alright. problem persists with gcc and clang however

Comment: Maybe this helps, `gcc code.cpp -lstdc++ -o runthis`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to compile C++ with a C compiler. Use `g++` (or `clang++`), which is a C++ compiler, instead of the C compiler `gcc` (or `clang`, respectively).  This is not a problem of GCC or clang – this is using the wrong compiler for your language!

The errors you're getting are because a C compiler, even if it correctly recognizes C++, will not try to link with the standard C++ library.